# Creating measures in a mongodb aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a report that has been developed in PowerBI. It runs over a collection of jobs, and for a given month and year counts the number of jobs that were created, due or completed in that month using measures.

I am attempting to reproduce this report using a mongoDB aggregation pipeline. At first, I thought I could just use the $group stage to do this, but quickly realised that grouping by a specific date would exclude jobs.

Some sample documents are below (most fields excluded as they are not relevant):

```
{
"_id": <UUID>,
"createdOn": ISODate("2022-07-01T00:00"),
"dueOn": ISODate("2022-08-01T00:00"),
"completedOn": ISODate("2022-07-29T00:00")
},

{
"_id": <UUID>,
"createdOn": ISODate("2022-06-01T00:00"),
"dueOn": ISODate("2022-08-01T00:00"),
"completedOn": ISODate("2022-07-24T00:00")
}
```

For example, if I group by created date, the record for July 2022 would show 1 created job and only 1 completed job, but it should show 2.

How can I go about recreating this report? One idea was that I needed to determine the minimum and maximum of all the possible dates across those 3 date fields in my collection, but I don't know where to go from there

Comment: I don't know what your report should look like, nor what "measures" are, but do you mean something like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WrjblfW7Z7E)?

Comment: You can extract the month and year from the date field - and thengroup on month and year fields only. You can use the [Aggregation Date Operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#date-expression-operators) for that.

Comment: hi @rickhg12hs - yes, that's very close to how I solved it. I had to use facets to group by the three different dates, and then i combined the arrays intone one, unwound and grouped again.

Comment: How about posting your solution as an answer so other readers can see how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using a facet. I followed this process:

1. Each facet field grouped by a different date field from the source document, and then aggregated the relevant field (e.g. counts, or sums as required). I ensured each of these fields in the facet had a unique name.
2. I then did a project stage where I took each of the facet stage fields (arrays), and concat them into a single array
3. I unwound the array, and then replaced the root to make it simpler to work with
4. I then grouped again by the _id field which was set to the relevant date during the facet field, and then grabbed the relevant fields.

The relevant parts of the pipeline are below:

```
db.getCollection("jobs").aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        
        // Stage 3
        {
            $facet: {
                //Facet 1, group by created date, count number of jobs created
                //facet 2, group by completed date, count number of jobs completed
                //facet 3, group by due date, count number of jobs due
                "created" : [
                    {
                        $addFields : {
                            "monthStarting" : {
                                "$dateFromString" : {
                                    "dateString" : {
                                        "$dateToString" : {
                                            "date" : {
                                                "$dateTrunc" : {
                                                    "date" : "$createdAt",
                                                    "unit" : "month",
                                                    "binSize" : 1.0,
                                                    "timezone" : "$timezone",
                                                    "startOfWeek" : "mon"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "timezone" : "$timezone"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "yearStarting" : {
                                "$dateFromString" : {
                                    "dateString" : {
                                        "$dateToString" : {
                                            "date" : {
                                                "$dateTrunc" : {
                                                    "date" : "$createdAt",
                                                    "unit" : "year",
                                                    "binSize" : 1.0,
                                                    "timezone" : "$timezone"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "timezone" : "$timezone"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $group : {
                            "_id" : {
                                "year" : "$yearStarting",
                                "month" : "$monthStarting"
                            },
                            "monthStarting" : {
                                "$first" : "$monthStarting"
                            },
                            "yearStarting" : {
                                "$first" : "$yearStarting"
                            },
                            "createdCount": {$sum: 1}
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "completed" : [
                     
                     {
                        $addFields : {
                            "monthStarting" : {
                                "$dateFromString" : {
                                    "dateString" : {
                                        "$dateToString" : {
                                            "date" : {
                                                "$dateTrunc" : {
                                                    "date" : "$completedDate",
                                                    "unit" : "month",
                                                    "binSize" : 1.0,
                                                    "timezone" : "$timezone",
                                                    "startOfWeek" : "mon"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "timezone" : "$timezone"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "yearStarting" : {
                                "$dateFromString" : {
                                    "dateString" : {
                                        "$dateToString" : {
                                            "date" : {
                                                "$dateTrunc" : {
                                                    "date" : "$completedDate",
                                                    "unit" : "year",
                                                    "binSize" : 1.0,
                                                    "timezone" : "$timezone"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "timezone" : "$timezone"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $group : {
                            "_id" : {
                                "year" : "$yearStarting",
                                "month" : "$monthStarting"
                            },
                            "monthStarting" : {
                                "$first" : "$monthStarting"
                            },
                            "yearStarting" : {
                                "$first" : "$yearStarting"
                            },
                            "completedCount": {$sum: 1}
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "due": [
                {
                         $match: {
                             "dueDate": {$ne: null}
                         }
                     },
                     {
                        $addFields : {
                            "monthStarting" : {
                                "$dateFromString" : {
                                    "dateString" : {
                                        "$dateToString" : {
                                            "date" : {
                                                "$dateTrunc" : {
                                                    "date" : "$dueDate",
                                                    "unit" : "month",
                                                    "binSize" : 1.0,
                                                    "timezone" : "$timezone",
                                                    "startOfWeek" : "mon"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "timezone" : "$timezone"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "yearStarting" : {
                                "$dateFromString" : {
                                    "dateString" : {
                                        "$dateToString" : {
                                            "date" : {
                                                "$dateTrunc" : {
                                                    "date" : "$dueDate",
                                                    "unit" : "year",
                                                    "binSize" : 1.0,
                                                    "timezone" : "$timezone"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "timezone" : "$timezone"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $group : {
                            "_id" : {
                                "year" : "$yearStarting",
                                "month" : "$monthStarting"
                            },
                            "monthStarting" : {
                                "$first" : "$monthStarting"
                            },
                            "yearStarting" : {
                                "$first" : "$yearStarting"
                            },
                            "dueCount": {$sum: 1},
                            "salesRevenue": {$sum: "$totalSellPrice"},
                            "costGenerated": {$sum: "$totalBuyPrice"},
                            "profit": {$sum: "$profit"},
                            "avgValue": {$avg: "$totalSellPrice"},
                            "finalisedRevenue": {$sum: {
                                    $cond: {
                                        "if": {$in: ["$status",["Finalised","Closed"]]},
                                        "then": "$totalSellPrice",
                                        "else": 0
                                    }
                            
                            }}
                        }
                    }
                
                ]
            }
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $project: {
                "docs": {$concatArrays: ["$created","$completed","$due"]}
            }
        },

        // Stage 5
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$docs",
            }
        },

        // Stage 6
        {
            $replaceRoot: {
                // specifications
                   "newRoot": "$docs"
            }
        },

        // Stage 7
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$_id",
                 "monthStarting" : {
                    "$first" : "$monthStarting"
                },
                "yearStarting" : {
                    "$first" : "$yearStarting"
                },
                 "monthStarting" : {
                    "$first" : "$monthStarting"
                },
                 "createdCountSum" : {
                    "$sum" : "$createdCount"
                },
                "completedCountSum" : {
                    "$sum" : "$completedCount"
                },
                 "dueCountSum" : {
                    "$sum" : "$dueCount"
                },
                 "salesRevenue" : {
                    "$sum" : "$salesRevenue"
                },
                 "costGenerated" : {
                    "$sum" : "$costGenerated"
                },
                 "profit" : {
                    "$sum" : "$profit"
                },
                 "finalisedRevenue" : {
                    "$sum" : "$finalisedRevenue"
                },
                 "avgJobValue": {
                    $sum: "$avgValue"
                }
            }
        },
    ],

);
```